# JavaScript - cross origin request blocked - non-server solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm a desktop developer that is trying to learn some web basics on the side. I've previously put together an asp.net mvc website that worked more or less okay and am currently working on a simpler, html/css/js only website.

A number of the pages on the website will contain images, with a number of pieces of data accompanying them, so I thought I'd put together a JSON with all of the data, including the links to the images and generate the image list on page load. The problem that I ran into is the JavaScript cross origin request when trying to fetch the JSON file.

I've looked around at solutions and most of them recommend spinning up a server - either asp.net or node.js to fetch the JSON from. Couple of questions:

- If I can write HTML that references image files, why can I not fetch a json from javascript? Is there a fundamental piece of understanding that I'm missing here?
- Is there any other way of using a JSON without spinning up a web server? Should I try embedding it into the HTML? Is that a bad idea?
- Any other pointers/links to resources with relevant info :)

// My JavaScript:

```html
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            buildGallery('test.json', '#gallery');
        });

        // Builds a collection of thumbnails from the json specified inside of specified div
        function buildGallery(jsonUrl, galleryDiv){
            $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(data){

                // Ensure the data is in correct format
                if (typeof(data) !== 'object'){
                    return;
                }

                // Build the gallery
                $.each(data['images'], function(key, image){
                    var thumbnail = '<img src="' + image['url'] + '"/>'
                    $(galleryDiv).append(thumbnail);
                });
            });
        }

    </script>
```

This is based of: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Is the website that you are requesting the Jason from running ok HTTPS?

Comment: Where does your "website" suppose to be hosted?

Comment: Currently it's not hosted anywhere - just playing around on my laptop, but I was thinking of just getting a domain and putting it up there as static html site. Currently its just plain old HTTP as far as I know

Comment: Are you sure you are not running from the `file://` protocol scheme?

Comment: It looks like Chrome is indeed trying to get the file through the scheme, but I am not setting it explicitly? I've updated the post above with my script code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: But your html page is loaded from the file protocol right? Then all the requests will be made from this same protocol. Run a local server to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Ross HTTP is a protocol sent by a server. Although the HTTP standard does not require it, browsers will only accept HTTP connections via tcp/ip. Which means that HTTP is only possible with a server. Non server solutions cannot use HTTP thus cannot negotiate CORS

Comment: to negotiate CORS you need HTTP (since CORS is a feature implemented as HTTP headers). You don't need a programming language back-end like node.js or asp.net or Java, though that's what most devs use. You just need a server. So you can do CORS even with Apache or Nginx or IIS. Read the respective server's documentation on how to configure HTTP response headers

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys! This sounds like a super basic thing that I should already know.. I haven't done much web development at all and less so when it comes to anything non-server based, so I don't remember coming across this before.. So just to say this back - this CORS issue comes up, because I am using the file protocol instead of HTTP and the file protocol treats everything as CORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues with what you are trying to accomplish with the provided code.

First, you are trying to make an [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) request to a resource that is not hosted on an **http** server. Ajax is a wrapper for **[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** which was designed for fetching resources using the [http protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). However, it can support other protocols such as file, and ftp.

Second, CORS is not controlled by the browser, it's controlled by the **http** server. Cross domain origin requests can work, but only if the resource you are requesting responds with an http header that allows your domain to access it. Since the resource you are requesting has nothing to do with **http**, it will probably throw an error.

*So why do images work using the [file://](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) scheme?* The `<img/>` tag supports loading resources using any scheme your browser cares to support. It turns out most browsers support it.

*So I can't get json into my app without an http server!@?* Yes and no. No because you usually cannot request a resource not served through an http server using XMLHttpRequest. However, you can still request resources through other means.

I recommend using the [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) API for reading files from the users filesystem.